# import c type defined in .lib file to python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, cpython, .lib

I have a third party C static library (.lib) that I want to exploit using python  , the provided header contains the prototypes of functions and declarations of some data structures , but it also uses some data types that are not defined within the header

example in "header.h"

```
typedef HANDLE            R_HANDLE;
```

the HANDLE data type is not accessible in the header , and there are some functions that use this data type as a parameter or as a return value

How do I export this data  type "HANDLE" to be used from Python functions ?

Is there a method of dealing directly with "R_HANDLE" ?

rem : for classic structs and c data types , I'am using the approach of Python CookBook, using ctypes

Thanks

Comment: `ctypes` can only leverage dynamic libraries (`.dll`, `.dylib`, `.so`, etc).

Comment: As for other data types, `ctypesgen` is a good approach.

Comment: `ctypes.wintypes` includes `HANDLE`.  However, if it is a static library then it has to be statically linked with a DLL or EXE, so you will have to write a DLL which uses the lib, then call that from Python.

What do you intend to do with the HANDLE when you get it into Python?

Comment: here is an example of a function taking Handle* as a parameter 
`RESULT OpenW( int set,  int32_t wxtimeout, HANDLE *handle) ` , @BrianCain i found there was an available dll

Comment: If it's using a Windows `HANDLE` then the header must include windows.h, or maybe winbase.h or winnt.h. The `typedef` comes from some included source file. As was mentioned, the `ctypes.wintypes` module has Windows type aliases, and a few of the common structures. It's very far from complete, but it does have the common handle types, which are all just void pointers.

Comment: @eryksun @cdarke i use  open a library (.dll ) and then try to describe the parameters of a function that takes a handle parameter , like :`wxopen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.pointer(HANDLE))  `

the interpreter raise an error : TypeError: _type_ must have storage info

Comment: It takes a `HANDLE *`? Use `ctypes.POINTER(HANDLE)` to create the pointer type. `ctypes.pointer` creates a pointer instance.

Comment: Thank you guys for the priceless tips it seems to be working now